# boolean function to determine whether an commerce order id exists?

Tags: 7, commerce

is there a boolean function that exists OOTB that allows you to determine if a commerce order id exists?

I'm trying to pass an order id and check if is actually an existing order regardless of order state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a function that returns only a boolean, but `commerce_order_load()` returns `FALSE` if no order is found so you can use it in an `if` statement quite happily:

```
if (commerce_order_load($order_id)) {
  // Order exists
}
```

If you want to be bit more militant about it you could use this:

```
if (commerce_order_load($order_id) !== FALSE) {
  // Order exists
}
```

But it shouldn't really make a difference.